# How to provide a trivial class constructors for members of a union?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, constructor, c++11

How can I provide a class that has constructors as part of a union?

I've read that any class that has a trivial constructor can be part of a union.  Especially with c++0x, I thought unions are supposed to be unrestricted.  Why is this `float4` class not suitable?  How can I do this?

```
struct float4
{
    union
    {
        struct { float z, y, x, w; };
        float v[4];
        __m128 xmm;
    };

    inline float4() { }
    inline float4(float x, float y, float z, float w) :
        xmm(_mm_setr_ps(z, y, x, w)) { }
};

struct float44
{
    union
    {
        float v[16];
        __m128 xmm[4];
        struct { __m128 xmm1, xmm2, xmm3, xmm4; };
        struct { float4 row1, row2, row3, row4; };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VC2010 doesn't implement that part of the C++0x spec yet.